# VBA Loop not returning any values, plus failure to terminate

Tags: vba, excel, loops, macros

I have written a bit of code that is intended to search cells in a column, see if they start with a certain string and then return a value based on that string in another column. I have two problems, firstly the loops don't actually return any values in columns 8,9,10 or 11. Also the second loop doesn't stop running? Here is my code

```
Sub Possible_solution_one()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For i = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

        If Cells(i, 2) = "Business://EXTRACTS/" & "*" Then
            Cells(i, 8) = "OBS(" & Cells(i, 2).Value & ",SHARE,#DI) OR "
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop
Next


For j = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    Do While Cells(j, 6).Value <> ""
        If Cells(j, 6) = "Business" & "*" Then
            Cells(j, 9) = "OBS(" & Cells(j, 4).Value & ",SHARE,DI) OR "

        ElseIf Cells(j, 6) = "CSTM" Then
            Cells(j, 10) = "PUM(" & Cells(j, 4).Value & ",#D7) OR "

        ElseIf Cells(j, 6) = "*FS" Then
            Cells(j, 11) = "FCON(" & Cells(j, 4).Value & ") OR "

        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
Next

End Sub
```

To give the situation I have 1 type of string in column B and 3 types in column F. Am looking to return different things in columns 8,9,10,11 based on b and D

Comment: Have changed those around but still am getting the same problems :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are **pattern matching** with wildcards, you need to use the **Like** operator. e.g. `If Cells(i, 2) Like "Business://EXTRACTS/" & "*" Then`

The Do While loops inside the For Next loops were unnecessary. It is also not a good idea to 'manually' increment the increment counter in a For ... Next loop.

The second loop was running forever because you were incrementing **i**, not **j**.

A [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) would make a better fit for the multiple criteria in the second **j** loop.

```
Sub Possible_solution_one()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
            If Not CBool(Len(Cells(i, "a").Value)) Then Exit For
            If .Cells(i, 2) = "Business://EXTRACTS/" & "*" Then
                .Cells(i, 8) = "OBS(" & .Cells(i, 2).Value & ",SHARE,#DI) OR "
            End If
        Next i

        For j = 2 To .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
            Select Case .Cells(j, 6).Value
                Case "Business*"
                    .Cells(j, 9) = "OBS(" & Cells(j, 4).Value & ",SHARE,DI) OR "
                Case "CSTM"
                    .Cells(j, 10) = "PUM(" & Cells(j, 4).Value & ",#D7) OR "
                Case "*FS"
                    .Cells(j, 11) = "FCON(" & Cells(j, 4).Value & ") OR "
                End If
            End Select
        Next j
    End With

End Sub
```

I've also incorporated a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to associate all of the cells to the parent **ws** worksheet. Note hte `.Cells` and not `Cells`. The prefixing period assigns parentage to the worksheet referenced in the With ... End With.

With no sample data, I could not completely test this rewrite but it does compile.

Comment: It works!! thank you so much. Unrelated question, how have you learnt so much about VBA, I am very new to VBA but in the position where I will be using it alot in the future so am looking to do some learning in my spare time? thanks again for the help :)

Comment: If you want to examine real world examples, this site is one of the best. Looking through the [excel], [vba] or [excel-vba] forums, possibly sorted with the highest votes up top or searched for topics that are of interest is a great way to pick up tips and hone your skills. The better questions come with sample data that can be copied and pasted into a blank workbook and code that you can step through with [F8].

Answer (score 3):

your second do while loop uses i=i+1 instead of j = j + 1  so it's not going to increment the cells(j, 6).value if there's anything in cells(j,6) then the loop won't stop running

```
For j = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
Do While Cells(j, 6).Value <> ""
    If Cells(j, 6) = "Business" & "*" Then
        Cells(j, 9) = "OBS(" & Cells(j, 4).Value & ",SHARE,DI) OR "

    ElseIf Cells(j, 6) = "CSTM" Then
        Cells(j, 10) = "PUM(" & Cells(j, 4).Value & ",#D7) OR "

    ElseIf Cells(j, 6) = "*FS" Then
        Cells(j, 11) = "FCON(" & Cells(j, 4).Value & ") OR "

    End If
    'i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
Loop
Next
```

Comment: Good catch but I didn't find that the nested Do While .. Loop inside the For ... Next to be necessary at all.

Comment: totally agree - your answer was much more comprehensive